# Payfort Integration with Asp.Net MVC from server side

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, payfort

Currently, We are assigning the values in the below form and post the data to payfort. Which works fine!!

```
<form method="post" action="https://sbcheckout.payfort.com/FortAPI/paymentPage" id=form1 name=form1>
<input type="hidden" name="signature" />
<input type="hidden" name="command" />
<input type="hidden" name="merchant_reference" />
<input type="hidden" name="amount" />
<input type="hidden" name="access_code" />
<input type="hidden" name="merchant_identifier" />
<input type="hidden" name="currency" />
<input type="hidden" name="language" />
<input type="hidden" name="customer_email" />
<input type="hidden" name="payment_option" />
<input type="hidden" name="order_description" />
<input type="hidden" name="return_url" />
```

[But when we post the data throw above method it shows the credential information to others](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Pa8X.png)

Is there any way that we can post the data to payfort from our controller and redirect to posted URL ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can post data to payfort using .Net Client library https://github.com/payfort/start.net

steps to call payfort.

1) Generate card Token 
 pass open key and card detail.

2) create charge using card token

3) capture charge amount

Comment: 404 page not found

Answer (score 0):

You can use: https://github.com/payfort/payfort-dotnet-sdk/ 
this is official dotnet SDK from payfort